# Deploying Rails application from archive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I need to deploy a new version of a Rails server to a machine that doesn't have access to its Git repository. What's the best way to do it? Is there anyway to deploy a Rails server (preferably using Capistrano) from a prepacked archive?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the git repository on the local machine you can use the 'capistrano-git-copy' gem:

https://github.com/ydkn/capistrano-git-copy